# Local variable referenced before assignment global doesn't work

Tags: python, function, pygame

how can I make this function working? Is there a good subsitute for global??

```
position=0
score=0
eggY=300
eggX=0
def egglg():
    while True:
        global eggX
        global eggY
        if eggX<330:
            eggX+=5
            eggY+=0.8
        elif eggX>=330:
            eggY=eggY+2
            if eggY>450:
                terminate()
            elif eggY<450 and eggY>350 and position ==1:
                score+=1
                return
#rest of my code, with chaning position to 1 when i press w

egglg()
```

somehow it returns 0

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? Main things are it doesn't return anything, you don't print or use any of the values after `egglg` is called, and the error you're getting is for `position` which is never defined but you're checking if `position == 1`

Comment: i forgot to add it, it is same as eggY or eggX and its value is 0

Comment: yes, it is solved

Comment: Is the answer even acceptable? (check mark at the left of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to write to the global variables `eggX`, `eggY` and `score` you've to declare all 3 variables [`global`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt):

```py
position=0
score=0
eggY=300
eggX=0

def egglg():
    global eggX, eggY, score

    # [...]
```

Note, the variable `position` is just read, so there is no necessity to declare it `golabal`.